# Apache Tomcat Setup java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor

Tags: spring, exception, tomcat

I have just installed tomcat through the ubuntu package manager. I open the log and the first thing I see is an interesting exception.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor

Am I missing something in the installation?

It should be said that the reason I reinstalled in the first place was that I was giving my first go at webservices using Tomcat, and that didn't work. But for now: Why am I getting this exception?
I pasted the entire log out of kindness:

```
Feb 13, 2012 10:00:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 13, 2012 10:00:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.customizeBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
... 31 more
Feb 13, 2012 10:00:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 13, 2012 10:02:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 13, 2012 10:02:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.customizeBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:218)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
... 31 more
Feb 13, 2012 10:02:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Seems you didn't include the spring-asm-X.Y.Z.RELEASE.jar file in the classpath.

Comment: I realize I am missing a jar. Funny that isn't included in the package manager install when it cries for it before I even start using it. Any idea where I can get said jar?

Comment: Spring is NOT part of the standard Tomcat deployment. It's a dependency inversion container that you may use on your apps. That being said, it is your responsibility to add all the required dependencies in your webapp's classpath.

Comment: Then why is the vanilla Tomcat log full of exceptions before I even deploy a hello world service? That's what I would like to know. I am class not found messages asking for spring elements right from install. It makes no sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Tomcat is trying to deploy a web app that relies on Spring ASM but it can't find the JAR file for Spring ASM on the classpath.  I'm not sure what version of Spring your web app is using, but the latest version (as of today) for that JAR file is 3.1.0.RELEASE.

If you're using Maven, you can add the missing JAR file to your project by adding this to your project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven to manage your dependencies, then you can obtain org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar (or whichever version you need) by downloading 
the entire Spring Framework from http://www.springsource.org/spring-community-download.  The ASM jar file will then need to be placed in your project's WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I am not deploying anything. This is the log file straight out of install. I haven't deployed anything

Comment: On the other hand... This is not a new computer, so there might be something on the path somewhere its trying to start that a reinstall didnt kill. Ill look into that.

Comment: This machine has had Tomcat on it before. And it did have a special webservice holder setup, and lo, a war file was there. It had not been uninstalled. When I removed it and reinstalled the error messages went away.

Comment: If Tomcat was already installed somewhere else then I'd check to see if there are leftover TOMCAT_HOME or CATALINA_HOME environment variables pointing to the old installation.  You might be launching Tomcat using startup.sh from installation #2, but because of an environment variable it might be deploying a web app out of installation #1.

Answer (score 2):

The common approach to handle this situation

1) establish what jar library contains missing classs.

2) check, that this jar presents in your classpath

Comment: I realized that much, but I have no idea about what is missing, I have never in my life used spring and this is a completely fresh Tomcat installation acting up. I am writing this because I am having trouble following the common approach, as I have no idea what jar I need.

Comment: Seems, that Gabriel point to exactly jar in comment to question. Sadly I can't tell what jar are you missing exactly, since I don't know your spring version and others dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This error most possibly comes from the entries that you have in the web.xml. For example if you have this -  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet. !! So when tomcat starts, load-on-startup tries to find out the spring asm context, but probably deployment assemblyis missing the maven dependency jar (although the jar is available)  To resolve this try setting up the below

```
**Basiaclly In project options you should include Maven Dependencies to your Deployment Assembly** 

1.  Project properties-> Deployment Assembly -> Add.. 

2.  Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies 

3.  Finish

 Run mavem clean install and run on server. The error should go away.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was in 2 versions of Java installed on computer: Java 7 and Java 8. Unisntalling Java 7 solved problem.